# Cross-month events

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using resourceTimelineMonth FullCalendar.

Is there a way ot create cross-month events ? I'v searched in the docs but it seems that in this view, you can't see days of previous/next monthe. Am I missing something ?

For exemple, create an event that start the 27th of march and ends on the 7th of april.

Comment: `Is there a way ot create cross-month events `...do you mean by dragging to select, specifically?

Comment: For instance yes. The fact that the display is set for the current month only prevents selectin from the 27h march to the 7th of April. This prevents selecting the range, or resizing beyond the 31th. My idea would be to show the first 5 days of the previous and nextmonth to solve this but I don't think it's possible out of the box.

Comment: You're right it's not supported. Probably someone has made a feature request about it already - check the fullCalendar GitHub site and add your vote to it there.